# angularjs how to change two different append values separately

Tags: jquery, angularjs

i have a problem in two way binding,, i want to change each appended value name from shown field options, when i am trying to append two more fields i cannot able to change each multiple fields from shown single field, how to catch those appended id's to model? how to change each field name? i want to add two persons name and their email id's.. but when i'm trying to change those two names changing both fields name.. pls solve me this for to me..

you can see here in https://jsbin.com/sukibunuwe/edit?html,js,output

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('AddCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.field = {name: 'My Name', email:'abc@gmail.com'};
    $scope.add_NameField = function (index) {
        var namehtml = '<fieldset id="name_field" ng-click="selectName($index)"><label ng-bind-html="field.name"></label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" name="{{field.name}}"><button ng-click="removeName($index)">-</button>//click here//</fieldset>';
        var name = $compile(namehtml)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('drop')).append(name);
    };
    $scope.removeName = function (index) {
        var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#name_field'));
        myEl.remove();
    };
    $scope.selectName = function (index) {
        $scope.showName_Fieldsettings = true;
    };
      $scope.add_EmailField = function (index) {
        var emailhtml = '<fieldset id="email_field" ng-click="selectEmail($index)"><label ng-bind-html="field.email"></label>//click here//<input type="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="{{field.email}}"><button ng-click="removeEmail($index)">-</button>//click here//</fieldset>';
        var email = $compile(emailhtml)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('drop')).append(email);
    };
    $scope.removeEmail = function (index) {
        var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#email_field'));
        myEl.remove();
    };
    $scope.selectEmail = function (index) {
        $scope.showEmail_Fieldsettings = true;
    };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body ng-controller="AddCtrl">
 <button ng-click="add_NameField($index)">Add Name again</button>
 <button ng-click="add_EmailField($index)">Add Email again</button>

  <div id="drop"></div>

 <form ng-show="showName_Fieldsettings">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Field Label(?)</label>
   <br/>
   <input ng-model="field.name">
  </div>
 </form>

 <form ng-show="showEmail_Fieldsettings">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Field Label(?)</label>
   <br/>
   <input ng-model="field.email">
  </div>
 </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a form with two fields, now when you add `multiple fields`, changing one fields value also changes the other as the `model` is same.

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="FormCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="text" name="field_name[$index]" placeholder="name" ng-model="item.name">
        <input type="text" name="field_email[$index]" placeholder="email" ng-model="item.email">
      </div>
      <button ng-click="add()">New Item</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Controller code:

```
function FormCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];

  $scope.add = function () {
     $scope.items.push({ 
       name: "",
       email: ""
     });
  }; 
}
```

Below is a simple fiddle for the same:
http://jsfiddle.net/k3p1vxjm/1/

Comment: well done @thalaivar .. but i want to change one by one using only append method.. i have already tried by using ng-repeat and push events,, i have to add number of different type of fields like age, name, email, url.. after adding and given names i have to drag in my required place.. can u place try again for me ... thnx in advance ....

Comment: @VijjuSena: actually i am not getting, you want to add by one... then have to change separately means???

Comment: you given fields in html by using ng-repeat,, but i want to add all fields dynamically using append method..

Comment: @VijjuSena: which is dynamic right from what i see in your jsbin... on clicking on the add button, you are generating new name/email field

Comment: yes.. but con't we add and change field names through append method?

Comment: @VijjuSena: This is the statement which is confusing for me: i want to add two persons name and their email id's.. but when i'm trying to change those two names changing both fields name.. pls solve me this for to me..

Comment: you did exactly.. suppose i append  name, next email, next url.. if i want to add name after email. then what to do..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100059/discussion-between-thalaivar-and-vijju-sena).